# Что значат %d и %s?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Есть строки кода:

```
UNITUNIT_ID = %d
t.authordepartament_id in (%s)
```

Я так понимаю в первом случае, проверка равно ли значение переменной **UNITUNIT_ID** десятичному числу?
Во втором случае, находится ли переменная **t.authordepartament_id** принадлежит типу данных String? Но, есть только, варианты - VARCHAR, VARCHAR2.

Сам код:

```
   with ZVG as (
select 
 t.counter, t.unit_id, t.docway_id, t.petitype_id, t.result_id, t.docclass_id, t.docsight_id, t.checksight, t.countpeople, t.peticharact_id
from cards t,
(SELECT * FROM V_CARDSNUMBERS_RECEIVED WHERE 
--UnitCondition
 UNITUNIT_ID = %d) cn
where t.entity_id = 4 and
cn.card_id(+) = t.counter and
t.docindex <> -t.counter and
(
--UserUnitAndVisibleUnits
 t.authordepartament_id in (%s)
or
--UserUnitAndVisibleUnits
 t.regdepartament_id in (%s)
or
--UnitCondition
 UNITUNIT_ID = %d
)
--DateCondition
and (t.regdate between to_date(%d||'.'||%d||'.'||%d,'dd.mm.yyyy') and to_date(%d||'.'||%d||'.'||%d,'dd.mm.yyyy'))
),
```

Изучил Первые шаги Оракл, в разделе примитивные типы про String не указано.

Comment: А вы это откуда взяли? Выглядит странно. Можете показать весь кусочек кода или хотя бы побольше

Comment: А где у вас есть такие строки? В Delphi похожая штука была для форматирования строк. Выглядит так, как будто кое-кто не умеет пользоваться параметрами...

Comment: Показанное к oracle не имеет никакого отношения. в нем нет так работающих конструкций. Скорее всего это элементы обращения в БД или работы со строками другого языка программирования. Подобные вещи есть как минимум в C (а так же всех языках, заимствоваших из него функции группы printf) и питоне

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос.

Comment: Выполните запрос, ознакомтесь с сообщением об ошибке, прочтите ещё раз внимательно комментарии.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку вопрос задан в форме "Что значат %d и %s?", то, в принципе, ответ уже очевиден.

Некто, не знающий про параметры, собирает динамически строку с SQL-запросом на клиенте (язык семейства "C" или "паскаль", скорее всего), подставляя числа вместо `%d` и строки вместо `%s`. Работает (в Delphi/pascal) это примерно так:

```
a := 'Пользователь %s был здесь %d минут назад';
b := format(a, ['Вася', 5]);
// b теперь содержит строку "Пользователь Вася был здесь 5 минут назад"
```

Можно порекомендовать исследовать тему параметров в Oracle и в используемом клиентском языке/фреймворке, и переписать запросы с использованием новых знаний.